# $scope function is not defined (anonymous function)

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have this code:

```
  $scope.startTimer = function (){
    $scope.settings.showMinutes = false;
    $scope.settings.showStart = false;
    $scope.settings.showPause = true;
    $scope.settings.showReset = true;
    $scope.settings.showDonate = false;
    if ($scope.settings.seconds <= 0) {
      $scope.settings.seconds = 59;
      $scope.settings.minutes -= 1;
      if ($scope.settings.minutes < 0) {
        $scope.settings.showPause = false;
        $scope.settings.stopTimer = true;
        return;
      }
      setTimeout('startTimer()', 1000);
    } else {
      $scope.settings.seconds -= 1;
      setTimeout('startTimer()', 1000);
    }
  }
```

When I start `startTimer` function I get error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: startTimer is not defined (anonymous
>   function)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think you should pass $scope.startTimer as first paramater to setTimeout.

Comment: Please avoid passing string literals to setTimeout. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers.setTimeout#Passing_string_literals
They are called in global scope, not in your angular flavored $scope.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of:

```
  setTimeout('startTimer()', 1000);
```

Use the angularjs equivalent:

```
  $timeout($scope.startTimer, 1000);
```

**EDIT**: As suggested by Cherniv, it is important to inject the `$timeout` dependency to your controller, so if you have a controller named `myCtrl`:

```
angular.module("myApp").controller("myCtrl", ['$timeout', function($timeout){
     $scope.startTimer = function(){
        //Your code
     }
}]);
```